# Laravel table join and pass the value to view

Tags: php, laravel

this is my code

```
public function view( $sid )
    {
        $subpage = DB::table('subpages')
        ->join('categories', 'subpages.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
        ->where('random_id', '=', $sid)
        ->get('subpages.*', 'categories.category as category_name');
        
        return view('subpage_view', compact('subpage','category_name'));
    }
```

and I am getting error
compact(): Undefined variable `$category_name`
highlighting this line

```
return view('subpage_view', compact('subpage','category_name'));
```

Not sure what I am missing here.

Note:This is in subpage controller.
I am having similar code in category Controller
and that is working just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you do not have any variable named `$category_name`.

```php
return view('subpage_view', compact('subpage','category_name'));
```

is the same as

```php
return view('subpage_view', ['subpage' => $subpage, 'category_name' => $category_name]);
```

---

What you seek is already in the `$subpage` variable.

```php
return view('subpage_view', compact('subpage'));
```

```xml
@foreach ($subpage as $s)
    {{ $s->category_name }}
@endforeach
```